# How can encrypt all the form field values before submit the form and decrypt to view on jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, security, encryption

I want to **encrypt** all **form fields numeric value** just before submition of the form and **decrypt** then into the action class and process then accordingly. So that on the network the all numeric data would be protected and flow in a secure way.

**My approach:**
onClick of submit button **encrypt the all values using a method in JavaScript** and then submit the form and for viewing decrypt all fields value on form loading again via JavaScript.

**Is there any better and more reliable solution for this ?**

Comment: Just serve your web application over HTTPS only. You can't "protect" your submitted fields when the logic to do so is inevitably exposed on the client side.

Comment: You are right @ernest_k. I am using HTTPS but my intention is 1) to prevent the actual data (form field value) access on network by any person or tools. 2) If it's happen anyway then in that case they get only encrypted value not actual value.

Comment: As already commented, https is really solving your requirements (point 1, 2 and much more). What are you trying to solve what https is not providing?